Brave baggage BaggageField get value returns null
Here is my code
import brave.baggage.BaggageField;


BaggageField.create("appType").updateValue(Objects.nonNull(requestEntity.getAppType()) ? requestEntity.getAppType() : "-");
BaggageField.create("cdrCategory").updateValue(Objects.nonNull(requestEntity.getCdrCategory()) ? requestEntity.getCdrCategory() : "-");
BaggageField.create("idNumber").updateValue(Objects.nonNull(requestEntity.getIdNumber()) ? requestEntity.getIdNumber()  : "-");
BaggageField.create("connectionNumber").updateValue(Objects.nonNull(requestEntity.getConnectionNumber()) ? requestEntity.getConnectionNumber(): "-");
BaggageField.create("appLanguage").updateValue(Objects.nonNull(requestEntity.getAppLanguage()) ? requestEntity.getAppLanguage() : "-");

BaggageField.create("mifeTraceId").updateValue(requestEntity.getTraceId());

just after setting the values, I put these error logs to check whether values set correctly
log.error("VA_FIXES : Baggage value ={} ", BaggageField.getAllValues());
                        log.error("VA_FIXES : Baggage value ={} ", 
BaggageField.getAllValues().get("mifeTraceId"));
                        log.error("VA_FIXES : Baggage value ={} ",
BaggageField.getAllValues().get("appType"));
                        log.error("VA_FIXES : Baggage value ={} ",
BaggageField.getAllValues().get("cdrCategory"));
                        log.error("VA_FIXES : Baggage value ={} ",
BaggageField.getAllValues().get("idNumber"));
                        log.error("VA_FIXES : Baggage value ={} ",
BaggageField.getAllValues().get("connectionNumber"));

This is what appeared in the logs
2024-11-29 16:46:10.901 [, ] ERROR pod_ip: trace_id: response_time: mife_response_time: --- l.d.m.a.a.f.RequestLoggingDecorator : VA_FIXES : traceid=MDA380338455746
2024-11-29 16:46:10.902 [, ] ERROR pod_ip: trace_id: MDA380338455746 response_time: mife_response_time: --- l.d.m.a.a.f.RequestLoggingDecorator : VA_FIXES : MDC=MDA380338455746
2024-11-29 16:46:10.902 [, ] ERROR pod_ip: trace_id: MDA380338455746 response_time: mife_response_time: --- l.d.m.a.a.f.RequestLoggingDecorator : VA_FIXES : Baggage value =null
2024-11-29 16:46:10.902 [, ] ERROR pod_ip: trace_id: MDA380338455746 response_time: mife_response_time: --- l.d.m.a.a.f.RequestLoggingDecorator : VA_FIXES : Baggage value =null
2024-11-29 16:46:10.902 [, ] ERROR pod_ip: trace_id: MDA380338455746 response_time: mife_response_time: --- l.d.m.a.a.f.RequestLoggingDecorator : VA_FIXES : Baggage value =null
2024-11-29 16:46:10.902 [, ] ERROR pod_ip: trace_id: MDA380338455746 response_time: mife_response_time: --- l.d.m.a.a.f.RequestLoggingDecorator : VA_FIXES : Baggage value =null
2024-11-29 16:46:10.902 [, ] ERROR pod_ip: trace_id: MDA380338455746 response_time: mife_response_time: --- l.d.m.a.a.f.RequestLoggingDecorator : VA_FIXES : Baggage value =null

All the values are null.
springframework-boot version is 3.3.4
spring-cloud-starter-sleuth version is 3.0.2

I tries below two approaches.

approach 1

BaggageField mifeTraceField = BaggageField.create("mifeTraceId");

mifeTraceField.updateValue(requestEntity.getTraceId());


// Validate immediately
String currentTraceId = mifeTraceField.getValue();
if (currentTraceId != null && currentTraceId.equals(requestEntity.getTraceId())) {
    log.error("VA_FIXES mifeTraceId successfully set: {}", currentTraceId);
} else {
    log.error("VA_FIXES mifeTraceId setting failed. Current value: {}", currentTraceId);
                        }

Output
2024-11-29 16:46:10.902 [, ] ERROR pod_ip: trace_id: MDA380338455746 response_time: mife_response_time: --- l.d.m.a.a.f.RequestLoggingDecorator : VA_FIXES mifeTraceId setting failed. Current value: null

approach 2

Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> {
    String traceId = BaggageField.getAllValues().get("mifeTraceId");
    log.error("VA_FIXES mifeTraceId in reactive context: {}", traceId);
    return Mono.empty();
}).subscribe();`

Output
2024-11-29 16:46:10.903 [, ] ERROR pod_ip: trace_id: MDA380338455746 response_time: mife_response_time: --- l.d.m.a.a.f.RequestLoggingDecorator : VA_FIXES mifeTraceId in reactive context: null
Still I get null in return.
If anyone know the reason for this or how to fix this, would be a great help.
